# Keep Iphone browser from turning numbers into links

Tags: html, browsers, iphone

I'm writing a very simple page that is supposed to be viewed on mobile devices. While viewing it in the iphone simulator I noticed that the iphone browser automatically turns any number string into a link, supposedly for dialing it directly.

Problem is - there are a ton of numbers on my page that LOOK like phone numbers but actually aren't. Is there a way to tell the iphone browser to leave these numbers alone?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Very poor implementation on Apple's part (I hear this also happens on the iPad, where it makes no sense whatsoever), but there is a fix:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

Source: 
http://www.darowski.com/tracesofinspiration/2009/03/31/stop-iphone-from-incorrectly-auto-linking-phone-numbers/

One of the comments on that page also suggests the use of the controversial soft hyphen (`&shy;`) to prevent auto-linking of a specific number (so the browser can still auto-link other numbers on the page).

---

#### Additional Info

If you want to link certain numbers but not others, I would personally use the `format-detection` meta tag to disable autolinking numbers, and then explicitly link the ones that are phone numbers:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Foo Co.</h1>
  <dl>
    <dt>Phone</dt>
    <dd><span itemprop="telephone"><a
      href="<?php echo ($isMobile? 'tel' : 'callto') ?>:+15555555555">
      555-555-5555</a>
    </span></dd>
    <dt>Client ID</dt>
    <dd>1234567890</dd>
</div>
```

The PHP snippet is there to swap out the `tel:` scheme for `callto:` if it's not a mobile browser. This way Skype and other desktop VoIP programs can be triggered when the link is clicked.

Comment: This is a great solution, but what if there are only certain numbers that you don't want converted to links? Is there a way to do it by class or attributes only?

Comment: @Dan: There's really no ideal way to do that beyond using `&shy;` to break up the number. What I would do is to disable iOS' Safari's auto-linking of numbers and then just explicitly indicate which numbers are actual phone numbers using semantic markup.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the best solution for my particular case. Thanks!

Comment: I had the problem with incomplete dates like `2020-01`. For these cases, it is possible to wrap them with the html [time tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_time.asp), e.g. `<time datetime="2020-01">2020-01</time>`. This also prevents the call number detection.